# warning: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

Tags: java, ant, hudson

I encounter this error (warning: unmappable character for encoding ASCII) 
when compiling the files using apache-ant-1.7.0 through hudson build server can anyone advise on how to resolve this? I am able to build successfully using windows machine.

Comment: A assume that you run Hudson as a different user and or on a different platform than your reference build on Windows. If that is true, try ti run it with the same user on the same environment than Hudson. Also, have a look a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464874/unmappable-character-for-encoding-warning-in-java

Comment: Found another nice explanation: http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/unmappable_character_for_encoding_ascii

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you're compiling source code that contains non-ASCII characters with your platform default encoding (used by javac) set to US-ASCII.

All you have to do is use the `encoding` attribute of the [`javac` Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) to specify the encoding you're using to write your source code.