# é becomes &195;#169 and then becomes Ã© How do I fix this encoding issue?

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, pdf-generation, maven

I have a java file in Eclipse that is in UTF-8 and has some strings containing accents.

In the java file itself, the accent is written and saved as **é** .
In the xml that is generated using velocity the **é** becomes `&#195;&#169;`
In the pdf that is generated using fop and and an xsl template, the output is displayed as **Ã©**

So this is probably an encoding issue and everything should be in UTF-8. What's weird is that locally in my eclipse environment (windows) where I run the application, the whole process works and the correct accents **é** are displayed in the pdf.

However when the application is built with maven and deployed to a (unix environment) I see the problem described above.

Comment: Not sure about the Maven/Velocity/PDF-generator parts, but this sounds much like as if the transfer to Unix didn't treat textbased files as UTF-8. Open the files in a UTF-8 capable editor in Unix and take a look to exclude one and other.

Comment: A minor point but java files are usually either UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: @GaryF: I think you're a bit confused between *.java* file encoding and the JVM's internal string representation.  A *.java* file is just a text file, with no metadata and its encoding depends solely on the editor you use to create the file.  For example if I type an 'é' in IntelliJ IDEA (my Java IDE of choice) and save the file, it is going to be saved, by default, as a UTF-8 file.  In addition to that, I've got a really hard time remembering the last time I saw a *.java* file encoded as UCS-2.

Comment: In eclipse you can right click on a java file and choose any text file encoding including UTF-8.

Comment: @Ayrad: I've written here that strings containing non-ASCII characters should be externalized to files and not put directly in *.java* file **OR** you'll have a lot of issues, including but not limited to problematic batch/scripting, encoding issues when transfering the file to/from various OSes, IDEs, text editors, etc.  Some people have problems understanding this **fact** that said.  Out of curiosity, what happens if you use the *\u00E9* escape in your .java source file?

Comment: Good point about externalizing the strings I should probably do that. I will also try with the \u00E9 and report back but it feels like a workaround.

Comment: @Aryad The troublesome **é** in your source code appears in a String or char literal (that is, in quotes, like `"gloph dréusse"` or `'é'`), right? And the Java code is passing it to Velocity without sending it to a file first, or over the network, or anything like that?

Comment: @Webinator - Fair point. I had always (erroneously) assumed that files matched the string encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps Eclipse is compiling the file with a different `javac` command line than Maven.

When you compile Java, you have to tell the compiler the encoding of the source files (if they contain non-ASCII characters and the default doesn't work).

```
javac -encoding utf8 MyCode.java
```

I *think* the way to fix this in Maven is to add this to your pom.xml file:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

(I got that from [a Maven FAQ about a slightly different issue](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning).)

You could instead avoid the encoding issue entirely by using ugly Unicode escape sequences in your Java file. `é` would become `\u00e9`. Worse for humans, easier for the toasters. (As Perlis said, "In man-machine symbiosis, it is man who must adjust: The machines can't.")

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works locally in Windows. As far I understand, build/compile happens on Windows and then the files are transferred to Unix. Using the unicode escapes is however a good suggestion as workaround/prevention.

Comment: @BalusC My theory is that the Eclipse build is different from the Maven build.

Comment: +1... Exactly.  Unicode escape sequences and string externalization if needed.

Comment: Ah, I thought that when you're using Maven in Eclipse, that it will then build by Maven. But I shouldn't think about Maven since I don't use it :) You may indeed be right about that point.

Comment: @BalusC: I know, I know... Which is precisely why I'm right everytime single time I write that developers putting non-escaped non-ASCII characters in *.java* source file should be shot to death: there are a **LOT** of very weird issues that can crop up.  Here we're just talking about Eclipse/Maven.  Add a mix of IntelliJ, OS X, Un*xes and batch/scripts to the mix and you'll see why here I made it mandatory to use a custom Ant task that **forces** *.java* files to be ASCII only (build fails if you fail to comply with this)

Comment: Well, the firing squad seems a bit extreme. But even the legendary Jon Skeet says it's easier to use `\u` escapes:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464874/unmappable-character-for-encoding-warning-in-java/464886#464886

Comment: (I blame the designers of the Java language for not specifying what encoding a file uses, and the javac designers for using the platform-specific default encoding. In hindsight, it's obvious that the meaning of a Java source file should have been platform-independent. Oops.)

Comment: @Jason Orendorff: +1 to your comment about responsibilities. However now we're "stuck" with this sad state of affair and escaping (or externalization) is what we're left with :-/