# Bad accent characters encoding in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a string in groovy which has accent characters. I need to read this value as it is including the accent characters. Currently, the accent character is getting converted to a **'Ã©'**.

I tried to use `StringUtils.stripAccents`. It converts the accent character to **"Ã©"**.

```
String input = StringUtils.stripAccents("Gendé");
```

I expect to get **"Gendé"** but get **"GendÃ©"**

Comment: your problem is not clear. if `StringUtils.stripAccents` method returns wrong result - then do not use it.

Comment: The output  "GendÃ©" looks mire like an encoding problem unrelated to groovy or stripAccents, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325952/%C3%A9-becomes-195169-and-then-becomes-%C3%83-how-do-i-fix-this-encoding-issue. Basically the String is already "GendÃ©" before stripAccents() is called, and stripAccents leaves it unchanged. You need to set the encoding of your source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [é becomes &195;#169 and then becomes Ã© How do I fix this encoding issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325952/%c3%a9-becomes-195169-and-then-becomes-%c3%83-how-do-i-fix-this-encoding-issue)

Comment: If the related question does not help, you need to explain more of your setup and code. Which IDE are you using, where does the String "Gendé" come from, what tool are you running where you see the output?