# compiling Persian characters in javac

Tags: compilation, javac

I have to define a string which consists persian text. But by running javac on my program i see "unmappable character for encoding cp1252 " by trying `javac -encoding ISO-8859-1` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464874/unmappable-character-for-encoding-warning-in-java). 
Now My program does not see any error but only numbers in text are shown and Persian characters  disappear.For example my string is "من 2 کتاب و 3 کامپیوتر دارم" which means I have two books and three computers. The shown text is just : 2 3.
By the wat when I use netbeans I have no errors and all text is shown but javac make those problems.